# How to verify a dynamic text using Regex in Robotframework?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testing, robotframework, automation-testing

I want to validate below text in Robot framework, wherein the text in bold is changing dynamically and I just need to verify the Format of those bold text not the content. Can some one help?

"We will start the activity at **308 JAMES ST, WARREN RI 02885**, effective **05/07/2023**.
A downpayment of **$12.34** is required to participate in it.
Interested users can register from **04/06/2023** in between **8:00 AM to 05:00 PM** everyday."

I am using below code

${Regex}= Set Variable  We will start the activity at [0-9]+ ([A-Za-z]+( [A-Za-z]+)+), ([A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)+), effective (([+-]?(?=.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:.?\d*))(?:Ee)?(/([+-]?(?=.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:.?\d*))(?:Ee)?)+) A downpayment of $[0-9]*.[0-9]+ is required to participate in it.  Interested users can register from ([0-9]+(/[0-9]+)+) in between 8:00 AM to 05:00 PM everyday.

${Original text} = Get element attribute    #It is giving the text I provided above.

Should Match Regexp  ${Original text}  ${Regex}

Please help. I have dependencies on this regex concepts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In addition to your code, it would be useful to provide an example of the HTML tag with the text under question and the regexp pattern that doesn't work for you. Preliminary, you need to use two keywords: `Get text` from [SeleniumLibrary](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Text) to get text, and then `Should Match Regexp` from [BuiltIn](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Match%20Regexp) to verify that text matches the pattern.

Comment: @SamMaksymyshyn : added code. Can you please check and let me know

Comment: I am not well aware of Regex concept. I tried building few but nothing worked. So I opted to go to a website where it gives me Regex. But still it dint work.